# Chinese postman application

Tags: android, maps

Is there an application that would assist me in visiting every road inside a user specified zone ?  The (theoretical) problem is named Chinese postman problem (CPP), postman tour or route inspection problem. I am looking for an actual usable, user friendly implementation for Android.
I would like the directions to adapt dynamically to what I have already visited, as I may not be able to visit every road in on trip.